# What are the terminals in this 6 pin potentiometer?

Tags: resistors, components, resistance, potentiometer

I want to use my 6 pin potentiometer in circuits so I want to know what all the terminals are for. I know the basic principle in the 3 pin pot. I'm completely new so please answer it in simple terms. I have attached a circuit which I want to make which pins do I use for it.

I have also checked readings with a multimeter here they are, I have numbered the pins from 1 to 6 starting from left here are the readings:

- Pins 1-6 shows a range of 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob.
- Pins 1-2 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms.
- Pins 2-6 shows only 53k ohms no matter what position the knob is in.
- Pins 3-4 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms.
- Pins 3-5 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms.
- Pins 4-5 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms.

I was thinking that 4-5 should only be at 53k ohms and not vary but it varies.

Here's what my pot looks like:

[image]

And here is the circuit I want to use it in:

[image]

Comment: It is most likely a dual potentiometer (one knob two independent potentiometer), but you will need to find the part number and look up the datasheet to know the pinout, you can also figure it out using a multimeter

Comment: If you have a bunch of these and can sacrifice one, it would be mildly interesting/educational to bend back the four fingers holding the metal cover on and see how they have arranged the two wipers and two elements (presumably concentric).

Comment: One of these I have seen with 6 inline pins uses one element on the back of the board and one on the front.

Comment: +crasic   I have updated the readings in the details and also attached the circuit I wish to make please tell me which pins I should connect for the circuit

Comment: +SpehroPefhany no unfortunately this is my only pot

Comment: Set one of the varying pairs to the middle (25K or so), then check each pin to all 5 other pins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Check the datasheet for the TT Electronics P120KGE, it appears to be your exact potentiometer:
[image]

This appears to be a standard dual potentiometer, commonly used as a volume control in stereo audio applications. It contains 2 individual potentiometers, connected to a common shaft, so it has 2 wipers and 4 outer terminals.

In order to determine the pinout, first you will need to find the resistance of the potentiometer, which is usually marked on the back. There should be 2 sets of 2 pins that show that resistance between them no matter what position the knob is in, and those are the outer terminals. The remaining 2 pins are the wipers. The resistance between them and the connected outer terminals will vary when the knob is turned.

Comment: Ok I have checked the pins with a multimeter I've numbered the pins from left starting from 1 to 6

Comment: +jBot-42, Here are the readings  Pins  1-6 shows a range of 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 1-2 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 2-6 show only 53k ohms no matter what position the knob is in. Pins 3-4 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 3-5 shows 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 4-5 shows a range of 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. I was thinking that 4-5 should only be at 53k ohms and not vary but it varies.

Comment: I have updated the details with the circuit I am making please tell me which pins I have to connect.

Comment: @KousikRajesh look at the little diagram in the bottom left of JBot-42's image. That's how its wired logically. Notice the numbers 1,2,3 and then in circles 1,2,3. Then look at the bottom right, they are marked how the pot is wired physically. That matches how you described it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, these are dual pots used in audio circuits. It is not easy to say what this does without looking through the datasheet or probing. I would suggest going through with a multimeter and ohming it out.

Comment: +mcmiln, I have got the readings here they are I have numbered the pins 1-6 starting from the left.

Comment: Here are the readings Pins 1-6 shows a range of 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 1-2 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 2-6 show only 53k ohms no matter what position the knob is in. Pins 3-4 show 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 3-5 shows 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. Pins 4-5 shows a range of 0 ohms to 53k ohms when I turn the knob. I was thinking that 4-5 should only be at 53k ohms and not vary but it varies.

Comment: I have updated the details with the circuit I am making please tell me which pins I have to connect.

Comment: Right off the bat, you will need to put another piece in this puzzle. If this pot goes to 53k and you need 100k, put something in series. This will mean you have a more limited range of R1 + variable R2. Other than that you need a bigger pot. Now I am not sure if this is truly a 6 pin trimming pot or a dual pot. If it is a dual pot, then you have your two pots to put in series. If not, then trimming pots works by having two endpoint pins, sometimes a center-point, and the rest are trimming pins to change the resistance curve. I hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Its simply a 2-in-1 potentiometer of the value indicated at the back.

As in 3-pin potentiometer, the outer two pins are for fixed max resistance, then the middle pin is the wiper.

The pins at the back, is just a replica of whats at the front

Comment: Thanks for trying. However: (a) FYI, the question was already answered 4 years ago. (b) Your answer doesn't actually answer the question, about which pin does what. You said: "*The pins at the back, is just a replica of whats at the front*" There are no "back" and "front" pins, as the potentiometer in the question has 6 pins **in a single row**. "*As in 3-pin potentiometer, the outer two pins are for fixed max resistance, then the middle pin is the wiper*" Not true. See the diagram in accepted answer - the outer 2 pins (of the 6-pin row) are not the fixed max resistance for one of the tracks.